# Is there any way to show "I/System.out" at every line in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to check multiple lines of log at "4:Run", which is at the bottom of the IDE.
However it is not arranged because of the string "I/System.out".
It shows like this.
[image]

So I want to arrange these lines like this.
[image]
It doesn't have to show "I/System.out".

Is there any way to arrange it? or make it not to come out "I/System.out"?

The code of the 19*19 array(calcScoreArray) that I wanted to show is

```
private fun printBoard() {
        println("---Print Board---")
        for (i in calcScoreArray.indices) {
            print("$i ")
            for (j in calcScoreArray[i].indices) {
                print("${String.format("% 5d", calcScoreArray[i][j])} ")
            }
            println()
        }
    }
```

Comment: try writing "System.out.println()" instead of just "println()" that always shows "I/System.out" in my run

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's because the Android Studio IDE version isn't same.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on this option , it will stop the lines from wrapping if they're too big

[image]

Comment: It's still same like this. https://imgur.com/ZpMvHbt

Comment: It should be unchecked

Comment: Actually it doesn't wrap the lines, It just sometimes show the "I/System.out", and it sometimes doesn't show it.